# Como puedo optimizar mi consulta usando mysql

Tags: mysql, subconsultas

Tengo esta consulta en mysql, mi problema surge cuanto uso muchos `CASE WHEN`, para no alargar el codigo, elimine los demas y solo deje estos que muestro a continuacion

```
SELECT D551.TipoOperacion,D551.ClaveDocumento, D551.FechaP,

(CASE WHEN D551.Ped=(
SELECT D554.Ped FROM Tabla554 D554 WHERE D554.idEmp = 4 
AND D554.Ped = D551.Ped AND D554.ClaveC = 'DH' AND D554.Fraccion = D551.Fraccion LIMIT 1)
THEN (SELECT D554.ComplementoC FROM Tabla554 D554 WHERE D554.idEmp = 4 
AND D554.Ped = D551.Ped AND D554.ClaveC = 'DH' LIMIT 1) ELSE '0' END) AS 'DH',

(CASE WHEN D551.Ped=(
SELECT D554.Ped FROM Tabla554 D554 WHERE D554.idEmp =4 
AND D554.Ped = D551.Ped AND D554.ClaveC = 'EN' AND D554.IdentificadorCaso = 'U' AND D554.Fraccion = D551.Fraccion LIMIT 1)
THEN (SELECT D554.ComplementoC FROM Tabla554 D554 WHERE D554.idEmp = 4 
AND D554.Ped = D551.Ped AND D554.ClaveC = 'EN' LIMIT 1) ELSE '0' END) AS 'EN U'

(CASE WHEN D551.Ped=(
SELECT D554.Ped FROM Tabla554 D554 WHERE D554.idEmp = 4 
AND D554.Ped = D551.Ped AND D554.ClaveC = 'TG' AND D554.Fraccion = D551.Fraccion LIMIT 1)
THEN (SELECT D554.ComplementoC FROM Tabla554 D554 WHERE D554.idEmp = 4 
AND D554.Ped = D551.Ped AND D554.ClaveC = 'TG' LIMIT 1) ELSE '0' END) AS 'XD',

(CASE WHEN D551.Ped=(
SELECT D554.Ped FROM Tabla554 D554 WHERE D554.idEmp =4 
AND D554.Ped = D551.Ped AND D554.ClaveC = 'FP' AND D554.IdentificadorCaso = 'U' AND D554.Fraccion = D551.Fraccion LIMIT 1)
THEN (SELECT D554.ComplementoC FROM Tabla554 D554 WHERE D554.idEmp = 4 
AND D554.Ped = D551.Ped AND D554.ClaveC = 'FP' LIMIT 1) ELSE '0' END) AS 'EN X'


FROM Tabla551 D551 WHERE D551.idEmp = 4 
AND D551.FechaP BETWEEN "2022-04-01" AND "2022-04-30";
```

las tablas no tienen relacion alguna, pero tiene algo en comun, que son `D554.Ped`, `D554.idEmp`,`D554.Fraccion` , estos datos son iguales en ambas tablas, cuanto son 2 mil registros la consulta se demora mas de 5 minutos en devolver los resultados.

Tambien intente usar un `INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN`, pero obtengo mas resultados de lo esperado, que son 604 registros al hacer JOINS, tambien intente agruparlos de por Ped, IdEm, Fraccion, pero obtengo menos resultados esperados, `GROUP BY D551.Ped,D551.PedCompleto,D551.Fraccion`

```
SELECT  SELECT D551.TipoOperacion,D551.ClaveDocumento, D551.FechaP,

IF(D554.ClaveC = 'DH' AND D554.Ped = D551.Ped AND D554.Fraccion = D551.Fraccion, D554.ComplementoC,'') AS 'DH',
IF(D554.ClaveC = 'EN' AND D554.IdentificadorCaso = 'U' AND D554.Ped = D551.Ped AND D554.Fraccion = D551.Fraccion , D554.ComplementoC,'') AS 'EN U', 
IF(D554.ClaveC = 'EN' AND D554.IdentificadorCaso = 'X' AND D554.Ped = D551.Ped AND D554.Fraccion = D551.Fraccion, D554.ComplementoC,'' ) AS 'XD',
IF(D554.ClaveC = 'EN' AND D554.IdentificadorCaso = 'X' AND D554.Ped = D551.Ped AND D554.Fraccion = D551.Fraccion, D554.ComplementoC,'' ) AS 'EN X'

FROM Tabla551  D551 INNER JOIN Tabla554 D554  ON D551.PedCompleto = D554.PedCompleto
AND D551.idEmp = D554.idEmp WHERE D551.idEmp = 4 AND D554.idEmp = 4
AND D554.ClaveC IN("DH","EN","MA","MC","PO","PT","TL","XP")
AND D554.Ped = D551.Ped AND D554.Fraccion = D551.Fraccion

AND D551.FechaP  BETWEEN "2022-04-01" AND "2022-04-30" ;
```

cuanto en mi consulta a la tabla 551 obtengo 204 registros que es el resultado esperado

```
SELECT * FROM Tabla551 WHERE idEmp = 4 and FechaP BETWEEN "2022-04-01" AND "2022-04-30"
```

como podria optimizar esta consulta

Comment: ¿Y no puedes simplificar tu consulta a un ejemplo básico fácil de entender para que podamos proponerte mejoras? ¿Cuál sería la estructura de las tablas? ¿Qué modelas exactamente?

Comment: @DavidJP necesitas la estructura de la tabla, y a qué te refieres con simplificar la consulta, para poder editar la pregunta, gracias

Comment: Sí, aporta las tablas, por favor. Me refiero a que la consulta incorpora un montón de condiciones que dificultan su lectura, quita las condiciones que puedas añadir después y será más fácil de entender para optimizarla

Comment: @DavidJP ya logre solucionar mi problema usando inner join, solo agregue un GROUP BY concatenando los datos, pero tengo otro problema cuanto hago un IF o un CASE WHEN, puedo marcar como solucionada mi pregunta, para realizar otra pregunta o me recomiendas actualizar la pregunta aqui mismo ?

Comment: Si ya tienes la solución puedes responderte a ti mismo y plantear una nueva pregunta con la otra duda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

muchas gracias, ya pude solucionar mi problema, mi solucion fue usar un `INNER JOIN` Y `GROUP BY`, al hacer el group by, tuve que usar concat para que me devolveria los registros esperados.

```
concat(D551.Ped,"-",D551.Fraccion)

SELECT D551.TipoOperacion,D551.ClaveDocumento, D551.FechaP,

IF(D554.ClaveC = 'DH' AND D554.Ped = D551.Ped AND D554.Fraccion = D551.Fraccion, D554.ComplementoC,'') AS 'DH',
IF(D554.ClaveC = 'EN' AND D554.IdentificadorCaso = 'U' AND D554.Ped = D551.Ped AND D554.Fraccion = D551.Fraccion , D554.ComplementoC,'') AS 'EN U', 
IF(D554.ClaveC = 'EN' AND D554.IdentificadorCaso = 'X' AND D554.Ped = D551.Ped AND D554.Fraccion = D551.Fraccion, D554.ComplementoC,'' ) AS 'XD',
IF(D554.ClaveC = 'EN' AND D554.IdentificadorCaso = 'X' AND D554.Ped = D551.Ped AND D554.Fraccion = D551.Fraccion, D554.ComplementoC,'' ) AS 'EN X'

FROM Tabla551  D551 INNER JOIN Tabla554 D554  ON D551.PedCompleto = D554.PedCompleto
AND D551.idEmp = D554.idEmp WHERE D551.idEmp = 4 AND D554.idEmp = 4
AND D554.ClaveC IN("DH","EN","MA","MC","PO","PT","TL","XP")
AND D554.Ped = D551.Ped AND D554.Fraccion = D551.Fraccion

AND D551.FechaP  BETWEEN "2022-04-01" AND "2022-04-30" 
GROUP BY concat(D551.Ped,"-",D551.Fraccion);
```